# Solve the differential problem given the initial values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the initial value problem :
>
> ### $$y' +ye^t = 0 ,\quad \quad y(0)=e$$
>
> $(a.)  \quad  y =e^2 e^{-e^t} $
> $(b.)  \quad  y =e^4 e^{e^t}$
> $(c.)  \quad  y =e^{-4t}$
> $(d.)  \quad  y =e^4$
> $(e.)  \quad  y =e^2 e^{-e^{2t}} $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). You should adjust the body of your question with your attempts.

Comment: Ezz, you should try to write out your question in the body using Latex, so people don't have to move off-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $dy/y=-e^tdt$, $y\propto\exp(-e^t)$. Since $y(0)=\exp1$, $y=\exp(2-e^t)$. This agrees with $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Set

$\dot y = \dfrac{dy}{dt} \tag 1$

for notational convenience (easier to type $\dot y$ than $dy/dt$!); then our equation is

$\dot y + e^t y = 0, \; y(0) = e; \tag 2$

note that with the given initial condition it is safe to assume that

$y(t) \ne 0 \tag 3$

everywhere; otherwise, by uniqueness of solutions, the only solution is $y(t) = 0$; thus it is safe to write

$\dfrac{\dot y}{y} = -e^t; \tag 4$

this leads us to

$\dfrac{d\ln y}{dt} = -e^t, \tag 5$

whence, upon integration 'twixt $0$ an $t$,

$\ln y(t) - \ln y(0) = \displaystyle \int_0^t \dfrac{d\ln y(s)}{ds} \; ds = -\int_0^t e^s \; ds = -(e^t - e^0) = 1 - e^t; \tag 6$

with

$y(0) = e \tag 7$

(6) becomes

$\ln y(t) - 1 = 1 - e^t, \tag 8$

or

$\ln y(t) = 2 - e^t, \tag 9$

from which

$y(t) = e^{2 - e^t} = e^2e^{-e^t}. \tag{10}$

The correct choice is thus (a).

***Note Added in Edit, Wednesday 27 November 2019 9:26 AM PST:*** To keep every jot and tittle in place, it should be observed that the transition from (4) to (5) technically requires $y(t) > 0$; but this can be handled by if necesssry reversing the sign of $y(t)$, i.e. *via* the transformation $y(t) \longleftrightarrow -y(t)$, valid since the given equation (2) is linear. ***End of Note.***

Comment: @Isham:  thanks.  Repairs under way!